# Why does this struct padding trick work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, padding

Consider this simple program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int   x1234;
    short x56;
    char  x7;
};

struct B : A
{
    char x8;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(A) << ' ' << sizeof(B) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `8 12`. Even though `B` could be packed into 8 bytes without breaking alignment requirements, instead it takes up a greedy 12 bytes.

It would be nice to have `sizeof(B) == 8`, but the answer to
[Is the size of a struct required to be an exact multiple of the alignment of that struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637774) suggests that there isn't a way.

I was therefore surprised when the following

```
struct MakePackable
{
};

struct A : MakePackable
{
    int   x1234;
    short x56;
    char  x7;
};

struct B : A
{
    char x8;
};
```

printed `8 8`.

What is going on here? I suspect that standard-layout-types have something to do with it. If so, then what is the rationale for it causing the above behaviour, when the only purpose of that feature is to ensure binary-compatibility with C?

---

EDIT: As others have pointed out this is ABI or compiler specific, so I ought to add that this behaviour was observed on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu with the following compilers:

- clang 3.6
- gcc 5.1

I have also noticed something strange from clang's struct dumper. If we ask for the data size *without* tail padding ("dsize"),

```
          A   B
first     8   9
second    7   8
```

then in the first example we get `dsize(A) == 8`. Why is this not 7?

Comment: Maybe there is no rationale other than compiler implementation details...

Comment: You're going to have to ask about a specific ABI, as there is almost zero chance this behaviour is within the scope of C++ itself. FWIW, I can't find anything in Itanium (at a quick glance) to explain this, though I do get `8 8` with GCC 5.1, so... :/

Comment: Does the tag [tag:language-lawyer] suitable for this question?

Comment: @NickyC: `s/Does/Is/`

Comment: Maybe this question can help answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006504/c-data-alignment-member-order-inheritance

Comment: I got `8 12` for the second code snippet under VS2013, it seems to be the compiler implementation-specific.

Comment: @zangw: Any difference with (the equivalent of) -std=c++14/11?

Comment: @PBS: actually, The C++0x features are enabled by default on the VS 2013 C++ compiler.

Comment: This is specific to your compiler.  A pretty similar case is [described here](http://lolengine.net/blog/2012/10/21/the-stolen-bytes).

Answer (score 3):

This is a data point although not a complete answer.

Say we have (as a complete translation unit, not a snippet):

```
struct X {};

struct A
{
    int   x1234;
    short x56;
    char  x7;
}

void func(A &dst, A const &src) 
{
    dst = src;
}
```

With g++, this function is compiled to:

```
movq    (%rdx), %rax
movq    %rax, (%rcx)
```

However if `struct A : X` is used instead, then this function is:

```
movl    (%rdx), %eax
movl    %eax, (%rcx)
movzwl  4(%rdx), %eax
movw    %ax, 4(%rcx)
movzbl  6(%rdx), %eax
movb    %al, 6(%rcx)
```

These two cases actually correspond to the sizes being `8 12` and `8 8` respectively in OP's example.

The reason for this is fairly clear: `A` might be used as a base for some class `B`, and then the call `func(b, a);` must be careful not to disturb other members of `b` that might reside in the padding area (`b.x8` in OP's example);

I cannot see any particular property of `A : X` in the C++ standard which would make g++ decide that the padding is re-usable in `struct A : X`, but not in `struct A`.  Both `A` and `A : X`are *trivially copyable*, *standard layout* and *POD*.

I guess it must just be an optimization decision based on typical usage. The version without re-use will be faster to copy. Maybe a g++ ABI designer could comment?

Interestingly, this example shows that being trivially copyable does not imply that `memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof b)` is equivalent to `b = a` !

Comment: I would guess this has to do with C compatibility. While a C++ program must know that any non-final type might be derived from, and therefore data members placed within the padding, no C program needs this assumption. When you derive `A` from some type, you cannot use the exact same `struct` in C.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a real language lawyer of C++, however what I've found so far is:

Referencing the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404423/c-pod-struct-inheritance-are-there-any-guarantees-about-the-memory-layout-of), a struct only remains a standard layout POD while there is only 1 class with non-static members among itself and its parent classes. So under that idea `A` has a guaranteed layout in both cases, but `B` does not in *either* case.

Supporting this is the fact that [std::is_pod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) is true for `A` and false for `B` in both.

- First case: http://ideone.com/jyPb5J
- Second case: http://ideone.com/bYcLXa

So if I'm understanding this correctly myself, the compiler is allowed some room to do what it wants with the layout of `B` in both cases. And apparently in the second case it feels like making use of what would otherwise have been the padding byte of `A`.

Comment: A standard layout class: _"either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members"_ `[C++14: 9/7]`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The wording changed with [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1813), and now doesn't make sense to me.