# Why does this c struct work？

Tags: c, windows, wdk

I see flow c language code in the windows driver kit(WDK) sample：

```
typedef struct _COMMON_DEVICE_DATA
{
    PDEVICE_OBJECT  Self;

    BOOLEAN         IsFDO;
    ......................


} COMMON_DEVICE_DATA, *PCOMMON_DEVICE_DATA;


typedef struct _PDO_DEVICE_DATA
{
    COMMON_DEVICE_DATA;

    PDEVICE_OBJECT  ParentFdo;

    .................

} PDO_DEVICE_DATA, *PPDO_DEVICE_DATA;
```

But when I want to test the smillar code , it build error.

```
test.c:14:6: error: ‘AA’ has no member named ‘flag’
     a.flag = 1;
```

Tesing code as fllow:

```
typedef struct __COMMON_DATA{     
    int flag;
}COMMON_DATA;

typedef struct __AA{
    COMMON_DATA;
    int x;
    int y;
}AA;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AA a;
    a.flag = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

All seem same as the window sample code, But where is it wrong?

Comment: don't use reserved name in your code base (double underscore, underscore followed by capital letter)

Comment: *"All seem same as the window sample code."* - In one code you use `a.flag`, in the other (as currently provided), you only declare some structure... The code are clearly different.

Comment: use vistual studio  build (the file extension is cpp),  error: C2039: 'flag' : is not a member of '__AA'.

Comment: Rename to `.c` instead of `.cpp`

Comment: to Holt:   I just want to know how can the wdk code works and  why simple test code build error.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax used in the WDK code sample is a Microsoft extension for structure inheritance in C.  But your error message looks like a gcc error message.

If you are actually using gcc, you could try building with `-fms-extensions`.

[Link to related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16523768/1505939)

Comment: A side note: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance . How can an AA be COMMON_DATA? It may have COMMON_DATA though.

Comment: I build it use gcc, also can use vistual studio.  I have  built it with vs2010, also error.

Comment: @user877329 the thread I linked to discusses that in more detail, I don't want to rehash in comments

Comment: @M.M I mean that with or without language support, inheritance is to the right thing here

Answer (score 0):

there is no member named **flag** because AA has no member named flag

```
typedef struct __AA{
    COMMON_DATA aa_flag;
    int x;
    int y;
}AA;
```

You should access actual flag in the COMMON_DATA struct not in AA struct

```
a.aa_flag.flag = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I know it. But  i want to know why the  windows  code works

Answer (score 0):

If you've compile this with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, you can see this warning before error:

```
./struct.c:6:16: warning: declaration does not declare anything
     COMMON_DATA;
```

It can be fixed with addition name of variable to code. This works fine:

```
typedef struct __COMMON_DATA{     
    int flag;
}COMMON_DATA;

typedef struct __AA{
    COMMON_DATA cd;
    int x;
    int y;
}AA;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AA a;
    a.cd.flag = 1;
    return 0;
}
```