# C - passing "composited/inherited" struct instance to a pointer of its base type

Tags: c, struct, valgrind

So, I have 2 structs.

The first one:

```
typedef struct AST_NODE_STRUCT {
    token* tok;
} ast_node;
```

The other one:

```
typedef struct AST_BINOP_STRUCT {
    ast_node base;

    token* tok;

    ast_node* left;
    ast_node* right;
} ast_node_binop;
```

Now, I have a method that looks something like this:

```
void do_something(ast_node* node) {
    ...
}
```

And I want to pass in an instance of the `ast_node_binop` struct...
No compilation errors are thrown if I cast `ast_node_binop` to a `ast_node` but valgrind says:

```
==6554== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6554== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6554== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6554== Command: ./cola.out examples/hello_world.cola
==6554== 
==6554== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==6554== 
==6554== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6554==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FE8
==6554== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==6554==    at 0x109B20: parse_expr (parse.c:88)
==6554==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6554==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6554==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6554==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6554==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6554== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==6554== 
==6554== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6554==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FD8
==6554== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==6554==    at 0x4A266B0: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:59)
==6554==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6554==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6554==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6554==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6554==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6554== 
==6554== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6554==     in use at exit: 4,587 bytes in 6 blocks
==6554==   total heap usage: 16 allocs, 10 frees, 9,281 bytes allocated
==6554== 
==6554== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6554==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6554==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6554==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6554==    still reachable: 4,587 bytes in 6 blocks
==6554==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I looked at this stackoverflow post: [Struct Inheritance in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114349/struct-inheritance-in-c) to see how to implement "struct" inheritance in C.

I basically just want to be able to pass in struct instances that are derived from another struct into functions that expects the base/parent struct.

What is the correct way to do this?
I will have multiple "derived" structs from `ast_node` , and I will not always know *which* derived struct it is, I just know that they will always be derived from `ast_node` Starting with: `ast_node base;` in the struct.

I know its confusing but hopefully you will understand what I am trying to achieve.

Here is `parse.c` since people in the comments said that valgrind complained about something else: https://pastebin.com/SvqeHKqs

Comment: Standard C is not an object-oriented language.

Comment: @Qubit oo patterns can be very well used in C, though.

Comment: The Valgrind output clearly states that you have a stack overflow in your program. But you didn't show relevant code.

Comment: Is it impossible to achieve this? @Qubit

Comment: There's no "magic" here.  You can have nested structs (a struct whose definition contains another struct).  In your case, ast_node_binop contains a *pointer* to the struct.  Which is perfectly legal :)  PS: Whatever's causing Valgrind to blow up - it's NOT* a coding error in what you've shown us.

Comment: @Swordfish Sure, but if this is the type of approach you want to take it might be better to use C++, unless there is a very specific reason C is required.

Comment: @paulsm4 So there is nothing wrong with the code posted above? I can pass the derived struct to a function that expects the base struct?

Comment: @SebastianKarlsson `==6554== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000`: You have a stack-overflow somewhere in your code, the code you show can't be the cause of that.

Comment: @Qubit "it might be better to use C++" tell Linus ;)

Comment: @Qubit The weird thing is, if I comment out where I pass a ast_node_binop to a ast_node pointer, no valgrind errors are shown anymore

Comment: I'm with Swordfish (and Qubit). Though I'm not experienced with Valgrind, there is nothing that states any problem with `do_something()` but a clear statement concerning stack overflow. I suspect it hasn't anything to do with the cast (or, at least, in a subtle way that is not obvious according to the exposed code). Btw. I've seen much of such C OOP things in `glib`. I doubt that it's wrong.

Comment: @SebastianKarlsson Do you call that function recursively? That could be the issue (and given the names I assume you do as it sounds like a tree). Recursively walking through a large tree is a common cause of stack overflows.

Comment: Okay guys, I will post exactly what is at parse.c line 88 which valgrin complains about, 1 sec, just gonna update the post

Comment: . o O ( One line will hardly be enough )

Comment: @Swordfish Don't get me wrong, I like C because of the low-level approach, but there are times when life can be made much easier using something else.

Comment: @Qubit I totally agree with you. Only having a hammer at hand makes everything sudenly look like a nail.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SvqeHKqs

Here is the whole thing.
But yes, I basically just wanted to know if I was doing it correct and since you said valgrind is complaining about something else, this post is no longer about the same problem and should probably be closed.

Comment: I dont know what can be wrong at line 88 though, since it is just the beginning of a function definition....

Comment: @SebastianKarlsson It's probably not there, that might just be the function it called and couldn't get enough stack to perform the call.

Comment: Valgrind is not the right tool for the job. Use a debugger to step through your program and find out where functions are called in an order and depth you have not considered.

Comment: Thank you @Swordfish
I actually solved the problem by using GDB instead.... The function was called recursively and ran out of memory D:

Comment: @SebastianKarlsson You can always replace recursion with a simple stack.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way. The errors posted don't have anything to do with inheritance or type conversions, but some manner of completely unrelated stack overflow. Perhaps you are using recursion or something - I don't know.

It is perfectly fine and well-defined to cast `ast_node_binop*` to `ast_node*` and then have that function access the data inside the `ast_node_binop`.

Formally, this is guaranteed by C17 6.5 §7, `ast_node_binop` is an aggregate that includes the lvalue type `ast_node` among its members. It is the first member of the struct, so issues regarding padding and alignment do not apply either.