# How does "struct inheritance" not violate the strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c, struct, standards

The "struct inheritance technique" in C ([as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059895/is-multiple-level-struct-inheritance-guaranteed-to-work-everywhere)) is made possible by the fact that the C standard guarantees that the first member of a struct will never have any padding before it (?), and that the address of the first member will always be equal to the address of the struct itself.

This allows usage such as the following:

```
typedef struct {
    // some fields
} A;

typedef struct {
    A base;
    // more fields
} B;

typedef struct {
    B base;
    // yet more fields
} C;

C* c = malloc(sizeof(C));
// ... init c or whatever ...
A* a = (A*) c;
// ... access stuff on a etc.
B* b = (B*) c;
// ... access stuff on b etc.
```

This question has two parts:

A. It seems to me this technique breaks the strict aliasing rule. Am I wrong, and if so, why?

B. Suppose that this technique is indeed legal. In that case, does it make a difference if **A:** we first store the object in an lvalue of its specific type, before down or up casting it to a different type, or **B:** if we cast it directly to the particular type desired at the moment, without first storing it in the lvalue of the specific type?

For example, are these three options all equally legal?

Option 1:

```
C* make_c(void) {
    return malloc(sizeof(C));
}    

int main(void) {
    C* c = make_c(); // First store in a lvalue of the specific type
    A* a = (A*) c;
    // ... do stuff with a
    C* c2 = (C*) a; // Cast back to C
    // ... do stuff with c2

    return 0;
}
```

Option 2:

```
C* make_c(void) {
    return malloc(sizeof(C));
}    

int main(void) {
    A* a = (A*) make_c(); // Don't store in an lvalue of the specific type, cast right away
    // ... do stuff with a
    C* c2 = (C*) a; // Cast back to C
    // ... do stuff with c2

    return 0;
}
```

Option 3:

```
int main(void) {
    A* a = (A*) malloc(sizeof(C)); // Don't store in an lvalue of the specific type, cast right away
    // ... do stuff with a
    C* c2 = (C*) a; // Cast to C - even though the object was never actually stored in a C* lvalue
    // ... do stuff with c2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So for question A, where in your example do you see an object having its stored value accessed by an lvalue expression that is not of one of the types listed in 6.5.7 (in [N2176](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf))?

Comment: @NateEldredge So let's take `A* a = (A*) c;
// ... access stuff on a etc.`. Suppose in place of the comment, we did `a->x = 10;` (suppose (`A` has a `int x` field). Would we consider `a->...` equivalent to dereferencing `a`, which results in an lvalue of type `A`, while the effective type of the underlying bytes is `int`, or `C`?

Comment: Years ago I participated in a long thread on this somewhere with several C language lawyers. Sorry I can't find it now. The upshot was that what you propose is invoking undefined behavior. The only definitely conformant cast is from the first element to the enclosing struct. Not the other way.  The upshot is that you'd need to declare the same first field in each "subclass," (logically indicating its actual type) and pass pointers to that field around as base class references.

Comment: Conversion of pointers has nothing to do with the strict aliasing rule in this situation. Given `c` pointing to some initialized `C`, consider that `c->base` accesses the `A` object in `C`, and, after `A *a = &c->base;`, using `a->SomeField`  is perfectly normal with no aliasing violation. `A *a = (A *) c` obtains the same pointer as `A *a = &c->base;`, just in another way. Regardless of how this `a` was obtained, it is pointing to an established member in an established structure, and using it conforms to the rules about accessing lvalues.

Comment: Similarly, after `C *c2 = (C *) a;`, we have a `c2` that points to an established `C`. The fact that the **pointer** came from a pointer to an `A` does not negate the fact that we now have a pointer to a `C`, and it actually points to a `C`, that is, it points to memory whose effective type is a `C`, and so using `c2` to access that `C` conforms to the rules about accessing lvalues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A. It seems to me this technique breaks the strict aliasing rule. Am I wrong, and if so, why?

Yes, you are wrong.  I'll consider two cases:

#### Case 1: The `C` is fully initialized

That would be this, for example:

```
C *c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
*c = (C){0};  // or equivalently, "*c = (C){{{0}}}" to satisfy overzealous compilers
```

In that case, all the bytes of the representation of a `C` are set, and the *effective type* of the object comprising those bytes is `C`.  This comes from paragraph 6.5/6 of the standard:

> If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an
>   lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of
>   the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access
>   and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value.

But structure and array types are *aggregate types*, which means that objects of such types contain other objects within them.  In particular, each `C` contains a `B` identified as its member `base`.  Because the allocated object is, at this point, effectively a `C`, it contains a sub-object that is effectively a `B`.  One syntax for an lvalue referring to that `B` is `c->base`. The type of that expression is `B`, so it is consistent with the strict-aliasing rule to use it to access the `B` to which it refers.  That has to be ok, else structures (and arrays) would not work at all, whether dynamically allocated or not.<sup>*</sup>

But, as discussed in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160454/2402272), `(B *)c` is guaranteed to be equal (in value *and* type) to `&c->base`.  Thus `*(B *)c` is another lvalue referring to the `B` that is the first member of `*c`.  That the syntax of that expression is different from that of the previous lvalue we considered is of no account.  It is an lvalue of type `B`, associated with an object of type `B`, so using it to access the object to which it refers is one of the cases allowed by the SAR.

None of this is any different from the statically and automatically allocated cases.

#### Case 2: The `C` is not fully initialized

That could be something like this:

```
C *c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
*(B *)c = (B){0};
```

We have thereby assigned to the initial `B`-sized portion of the allocated object via an lvalue of type `B`, so the effective type of that initial portion is `B`.  The allocated space does not at this point contain an object of (effective) type `C`.  We can access the `B` and its members, read or write, via any acceptably-typed lvalues referring to them, as discussed above.  But we have a strict aliasing violation if we

- attempt to read `*c` as a whole (*e.g.* `C c2 = *c;`);
- attempt to read `C` members other than `base` (*e.g.* `X x = c->another;`); or
- attempt to read the allocated object via an lvalue of most unrelated types (*e.g.* `Unrelated_but_not_char u = *(Unrelated_but_not_char *) c;`

The first two of those cases are of interest here, and they make sense in terms of the dynamically allocated object, when interpreted as a `C`, not being fully initialized.  Similar incomplete-initialization cases can arise with automatically allocated objects, too; they also produce undefined behavior, but by different rules.

Note well, however, that there is no strict aliasing violation for any write to the allocated space, because any such write will (re)assign the effective type of (at least) the region that is written to.

And that brings us to **the main tricksome bit**.  What if we do this:

```
C *c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
c->base = (B){0};
```

?  Or this:

```
C *c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
c->another = 0;
```

The allocated object does not have any effective type before the first write to it (and in particular, it does not have effective type `C`), so do write-to-member expressions via `*c` even make sense?  Are they well-defined?  The letter of the standard might support an argument that they do not, but no implementation adopts such interpretation, and there is no reason to think that any ever would.

The interpretation most consistent with both the letter of the standard and universal practice is that writing through a member-access lvalue constitutes simultaneously writing to the member and to its host aggregate, thus setting the effective type of the whole region, even though only one member's value is written.  Of course, that still does not make it ok to read members whose values have not been written -- because their values are indeterminate, not because of the SAR.

That leaves this case:

```
C *c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
*(B *)c = (B){0};
B b2 = c->base;            // What about this?
```

That is, if the effective type of an initial region of the allocated space is `B`, can we use a member-access lvalue based on type `C` to read the stored value of that `B` region?  Again, one might argue not, on the basis that there is no actual `C`, but in practice, no implementation makes that interpretation.  The effective type of the object being read -- the *initial region* of the allocated space -- is the same as the type of the lvalue used for access, so in that sense there is no SAR violation.  That the host `C` is wholly hypothetical is a question primarily of *syntax*, not semantics, because the same region can definitely be read as an object of the same type via an alternative expression.

---

<sup>*</sup> But the SAR nevertheless forestalls any debate on this point by providing that "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)" is among the types that may be accessed.  This clears any ambiguity surrounding the position that accessing a member also constitutes accessing any objects containing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It took me some time to process it all. To validate some of my understanding of the text: is it safe to say a common valid interpretation of the standard, is that doing `MyStruct my_struct->a = 10;` does two things: it sets the memory at `&my_struct->a` (for `sizeof(int)` bytes) to effective type int, and *also* sets the entire memory at `&my_struct` (for `sizeof(MyStruct)` bytes) to effective type MyStruct? (Where MyStruct has more fields than just the `int a`).

Comment: In other words: In my codebase I often create objects like so: `Something* something_new(int a, float b) { Something* s = malloc(sizeof(Something)); s->a = a; s->b = b; return s; }`. As you can see, I never initialize the memory at `s` itself - I only init the members. I understand from your answer that a reasonable common interpretation of the standard, would be that this is legal in terms of SAR and the rules in general, because `s->a = a;` would set the entire memory region at `s` to effective type `Something`. Am I correct?

Comment: @AvivCohn, yes, that is an accurate characterization of my comments.  The kind of behavior you describe of initializing an allocated object by assigning only to sub-objects, not the overall object, is very common.  (Sometimes a `memset()` is used, too, but that does not help with effective type.)  No implementation would be accepted that did the wrong thing with that.  Working backwards from there, we come to the interpretation of effective-type assignment that I presented, and which you recapitulated accurately.

Comment: I see. Another common thing I do in my program is the following (where `Object` is the first field in `SpecificThing`): `Object* make_object(size_t size) { Object* o = malloc(size); o->x = 10; return o; } SpecificThing* make_thing(void) { SpecificThing* thing = (SpecificThing*) make_object(sizeof(SpecificThing)); thing->y = 20; return thing; }`. I think that this code is legal. Do you mind validating if my understanding is correct as of why it is so? [...]

Comment: Inside `make_object`, `o->x = 10` sets the effective type of the entire region to Object (even though `sizeof(Object) < size`). After returning from `make_object`, inside `make_thing`, we have `SpecificThing* thing = (SpecficThing*) make_object(sizeof(SpecificThing));`. At this point, effective type at `thing` is still Object, not SpecificThing. This is legal, because SAR allows casting however we want - SAR only deals with *dereferencing*. Afterwards, by doing `thing->y = 20;`, we have now *reassigned* the effective type of the entire region to `SpecificThing`. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. For some reason this topic has been bothering me for quite some time.

Comment: @AvivCohn, I do not see any reason to fear that stacking initialization functions as you describe would be handled differently than you intend by any C implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this quote from C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5 7) should answer some of your questions (my emphasis added):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>   — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>   — **an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)**, or
>   — a character type.

Then more can be answered by this (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.2.1 15):

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

The rest can be answered by this snippet (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.22.3 1):

> The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to the
>   `aligned_alloc`, `calloc`, `malloc`, and `realloc` functions is unspecified. The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

In conclusion:

A. You're wrong. See the first and second quotes for the reasoning.

B. No, it doesn't make a difference. See the third quote (and maybe the first) for the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first element of the structure doesn't have any padding before it.

Second, when the type of an anonymous field is a typedef for a struct or union, code may refer to the field using the name of the typedef.
This is a good practice taken from the GCC manuals:

```
typedef struct {
    // some fields
} A;

typedef struct {
    A;
    // more fields
} B;

typedef struct {
    B;
    // yet more fields
} C;

B get_B (struct C *c) { return c->B; } /* access B */
```

Please check  [Unnamed Structure and Union Fields](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html)